# Is this memory usage pattern ok in an android app?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have been looking at my app's memory usage. And here's what I see in MAT.

[image]

According to the famous google io video, android's main resources are fine to have. But isn't 7.5 MB too much? And what is the remainder?

My app uses almost 35MB large heap and almost 30MB of it is almost always full. GC_CONCURRENT logs almost always show as 9% free or 7% free. Is that normal? Or am I having memory leak somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read what is [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). In android memory leak means that you create some objects and keep links to it, when objects already not used. (If you don't have any link to object - it will be collected by GC) So, the easiest way to see if you have problems with memory - to use your app for long time and see if allocated memory increases or not. If there is always X Mb - and not increasing - it's OK, even if X is quite big.

Comment: I have an infinitely scrolling list. When I start, it will be around 25mb. But as i keep scrolling it goes to upto 40MB. There will be a lot of bitmaps and json data that i store while scrolling. Heap size increasing this drastically is it fine?

Comment: No. If your users will scroll even longer - they will get OutOfMemoryException. You should release some memory or forbid infinite scroll